# CSS style for container with transparent border images

Tags: html, css

Want to make a page layout such as the picture below. There are three major components, `frameleft`, `framemid` and `frameright`. While `framemid` houses the page content, the other two components are just borders with transparent `.png` files in them.

Question is how to make `frameleft` and `frameright` scale properly with `framemid`? I found a similar question posed earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282489/div-w-border-images), but the technique described by the answer following the accepted one (which doesn't solve the problem at all), does not apply when the images in the side components are transparent.

[image: Layout]

My solution so far relies on housing these components in a div and setting its height manually. It's obviously not optimal, since I would ideally have the entire ensemble inferring this height from `framemid`.

**HTML** houses the three components inside a div with predefined height.

```
<div style="height: 500px">
    <div class="frameside frameleft"></div>
    <div class="framemid"> some content </div>
    <div class="frameside frameright"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS** scales the side images with respect to the housing component.

```
.frameside {
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}

.frameleft { background-image: url("frame_left.png"); }

.frameright { background-image: url("frame_right.png"); }

.framemid {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}
```

I'd rather not have to accept a CSS3 or HTML5 solution/trick, because this has to work with most browsers.

**EDIT**

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAesm/6/), courtesy of Warface, for a play-able-version.

Comment: I see you're using separate images for frame right and left are they different or is it just the same png with solid color and opacity?

Comment: Do you mind if it doesn't work in IE7? Also: does anything need to go in the left/right other than the background?

Comment: @Litek - different images. I see what you are getting at, and no they are not simple. let's say there's some pattern on them or something.

Comment: @thirtydot, I am willing to cut IE6, but not 7... If you have a solution for 7+, I think it could benefit the community if you posted it.

Comment: Does anything need to go in the left/right other than the background?

Comment: @thirtydot Oh, sorry, I missed your previous question. Maybe in the future - "yes", but let's say "no", for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anything need to go in the left/right other than the background? – thirtydot
>
> @thirtydot Maybe in the
> future - "yes", but let's say "no", for now.

If stuff might need to go in there, this is an option: http://jsfiddle.net/M5UqW/ *(try resizing the window)*

It works in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="frameouter">
    <div class="frameside frameleft"></div>
    <div class="framemid">content</div>
    <div class="frameside frameright"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.frameouter {
    border: 2px solid #444;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative
}
.frameside {
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0
}
.frameleft {
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/64x64/f0f/fff);
    left: 0
}
.frameright {
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/64x64/00f/fff);
    right: 0
}
.framemid {
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: #ccc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

Then look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/kAesm/3/

Set the html, body to 100% height then on the frameid set the min-height to 100% it should do the trick. Just remove the borders I've added to make it easier to look.

add

```
html, body{
   height:100%;
}
```

modify this too

```
.frameid{
   ...
   min-height:100%;
}
```

**LINK TO EXAMPLES**

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-3-column.htm

Comment: That's not the question. The question is "how to make the columns equal height?".

Comment: As thirtydot points out I'm solving my transparency issues with a png, and want to make columns same height.

Comment: Your updated jsFiddle doesn't seem to contain any `height: 100%`. *(by the way, not my downvote)*

Comment: @warface is you jsfiddle example supposed to be complete? Because it still relies on the height=500px set in the outermost div, if I remove that the ensemble vanishes with it. Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kAesm/6/

Comment: Well, that doesn't work because of two reasons - 1. what if the content is larger than one screenfull (http://jsfiddle.net/kAesm/10/), and 2. I won't want it to be larger than it has to be.

Comment: @Gleno Then this exemple should be the ultimate answer : http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-3-column.htm

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/kAesm/11/

Please add the below style

```
.container div{
    padding-bottom:300px;
    margin-bottom:-300px;
}
```

Above style will affect the three div(frameleft, frameid and frameright) and also you can add one more style that container part that

```
.container {
   overflow:hidden;    
}
```

below full part

Html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="frameside frameleft">Left</div>
    <div class="framemid">
        <p>some content
            sdfklsjdf
            lsdkfjsdlfkj
        </p>
        <p>some content
            sdfklsjdf
            lsdkfjsdlfkj
        </p>
        <p>some content
            sdfklsjdf
            lsdkfjsdlfkj
        </p>        
        </div>
    <div class="frameside frameright">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    height:100%
}

.frameside {
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.container {
 overflow:hidden;   
}
.container div{
    padding-bottom:300px;
    margin-bottom:-300px;
}

.frameleft {
    background-image: url("frame_left.png");
    float:left;
}
.frameright {
    background-image: url("frame_right.png");
    float:left;
    background:#ccc;
}

.framemid {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    background:#999;
}
```

Comment: +1 It looks good.  BTW: you should add the code to your answer. Even better would be to add the code and an explanation.  There's no telling if that link will always be there.

Comment: @jason Gennaro, I can apply the two style that padding-bottom:-300px; and margin-bottom:-300px. you can increase the pixels depends upon of the height of the page. Please check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  I know you didn't ask for a scripting solution but jQuery can do this quite easily.

```
var h = $('.framemid').height();
$('.frameside').height(h + 'px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/kAesm/7/

Comment: +1 for a workable solution... I really shouldn't use scripting for this one though, this is supposed to be a "works for everyone" page. I'm willing to let IE6 go out of spite, but that's it. :)

Comment: Thanks @Gleno.  Are you worried about those who don't have js activated or support for the lower versions of IE?

Comment: I am worried that some people might not have js enabled, and the page will look very sorry. I usually prefer not to rely on js to at least render the page correctly.

Comment: I think the % of those with it disabled is low.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121108/how-many-people-disable-javascript  Of course, I agree... a pure CSS solution is usually best.

Answer (score 0):

None of the jsfiddle examples i have seen 3, 6, 10 url are not working in IE8. Why dont you use a table and try it.