# height of <div> tag

Tags: css, html

I have 2 divs in my page: `<div id="firtdiv" style="top:100px; left:200px; height:unknown"></div> <div style="top:unknow; height:200px" id="seconddiv"></div>`

I will set firstdiv's height auto because I will put a datalist so I don't know it's height.
And secondiv's top property will change according to the fistdiv's height. Second div is bottom of firstdiv.

How can I do?

Comment: What is the problem with DIV? When its content grows, it will push the second DIV even without CSS.

Comment: Sir,
I wanna do this;
When firstdiv's height changes, seconddiv's property of 'top' changes.

Comment: So, DIV's are positioned `absolute`? or floated? 'Coz if not, its automatic. Now if floated, it is also automatic. Meaning you don't have to define the top's of the DIV's

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VWVcE/
look, content div's height is not 400px; It will change. I will write something and it's height will grow or not.
So, bottom div's "top" will grove or not..

Comment: You should explicitly set it to `position: absolute` if you're going to use `top`, etc.

Comment: Possible solution and duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769918/css-style-for-container-with-transparent-border-images/6769937#6769937

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest put two DIV's in a DIV (which is set to absolute). 'Coz when you set both to absolute, then there's no way they will push each other. Here's an example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        Content...
    </div>

    <div id="bottom">
        Botom..
    </div>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: -400px;
    width:800px;
}

#bottom
{
    border-top: 2px dotted #2259FF;
    font-family: ebrima;
    padding-top: 5px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    background-color:green;
}
#content
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    min-height:400px;
    _height:400px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

As you can see, I put your 2 DIV's in a parent DIV (wrapper). The parent DIV is set to absolute just like how you want two DIV's to be positioned. Two DIV's then not positioned to absolute so that first DIV will push the second div when its content grows. Also, if you want to retain the minimum height of the first DIV, put a `min-height:400px`, but be careful 'coz there's a problem with `min-height` in internet explorer, what you can do to make it work in IE is put `_height:400px;` coz IE considers `height` as `min-height`, IE will consider `_height` (with underscore) but not other browser, so it wont have effect to other browsers.

Comment: @dmrc I've edited my post. It should work now, I've tested it.